# Python UTF-16 unicode conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding

I'm using the below code to convert Arabic to Unicode UTF-16.

for example I have an Arabic text as مرحبا

```
unicode = ''.join([hex(ord(i)) for i in t.text])
```

this code provide Unicode string as `0x6450x6310x62d0x6280x627`

The format in which I need Unicode is `\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627`

I want to replicate this [website](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter)

using the above method I'm using `replace` method to convert 0x format to \u0 format but 0x format don't convert special characters as expected so I've to use replace method.

```
    unicode = str(unicode).replace('0x', '\\u0')
    unicode = str(unicode).replace('\\u020', ' ') #For Space
    unicode = str(unicode).replace('\\u02e', '\\u002e') #For .
    unicode = str(unicode).replace('\\u022', '\\u0022') #For "
    unicode = str(unicode).replace('\\u07d', '\\u007d') #For }
    unicode = str(unicode).replace('\\u030', '\\u0030') #For 0
    unicode = str(unicode).replace('\\u07b', '\\u007b') #For {
    unicode = str(unicode).replace('\\u031', '\\u0031') #For 1
```

Using the default python encoding, UTF-16 didn't provide encoding in \u0 format.

```
print("مرحبا".encode('utf-16'))
b"\xff\xfeE\x061\x06-\x06(\x06'\x06"
```

How can I get results in \u0 format as this this [website](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter) is providing in UTF-16 format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is just about how you represent the hex value. To get the string in the representation you want, you can use

```py
In [84]: text = "مرحبا"

In [85]: print(''.join([f'\\u{ord(c):0>4x}' for c in text]))
\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627
```

#### Short explanation

Consider the first character of the `text`:

```
In [86]: ord(text[0])
Out[86]: 1605
```

It has integer (decimal) value 1605. This in hex is 645:

```
In [87]: hex(ord(text[0]))
Out[87]: '0x645'
```

You can also use string formatting (for example [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) in Python 3.6+) to show it as \u0645:

```
In [88]: f'\\u{ord(text[0]):0>4x}'
Out[88]: '\\u0645'
```

The `x` in the format string means "hex". The `0>4` means that print it as 4-digit number, and pad it with zeroes.